# Allowing Source Security Group ALB Access with Public Host Name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

**Summary**

I'd like to lock down access to an ALB to only allow connections from a given source security group *in a different VPC and using a CNAME, NOT its AWS provided DNS name*

**Further Information**

- I've peered the source VPC and VPC containing the target ALB
- I've tried assigning a security group to the ALB allowing access from the source security group over the target ports, but that does not seem to provide access

I'm pretty sure the issue boils down to the usage of the non-internal DNS name for the ALB, resulting in IP resolving to the public - not private - IP of the ALB. What is the best way to achieve access restriction to the ALB while still using it's non-internal DNS name? Do I need to spin up an internal DNS server?

Comment: Try spinning up an ALB in the same location, but with `Scheme: Internal`. The help bubble says: "An Internet-facing load balancer routes requests from clients over the Internet to targets. An internal load balancer routes requests from clients to targets using private IP addresses." Be sure to resolve the DNS Name of the ALB _within_ the VPC so that it returns a private IP address. I'm not sure if the DNS name will resolve across the VPC Peering connection, so let us know what you find!

Comment: hm, my impression, though, is that as long as DNS resolution from accepter VPC to private IP is enabled, requests to the ALB should resolve to its private IP address. From the help bubble that appears when hovering over that item in the Peering Connection settings:

"If enabled, the public DNS hostname of an instance in the requester VPC resolves to its private IP address when queried from an instance in the accepter VPC"

Comment: Try it out and then we'll know for sure!